# Empty files created when deleting the first element in string

Tags: python, file

My code is -

```
import os


currentdir = "........."
resultdir="............."


for root, dirs, files in os.walk(currentdir):
        for name in files:
            outfile1 = open(resultdir + "/" + name, "w+")
            #outfile1 = open(resultdir + "/" + name, "w+")
            print(name)
            outfile2 = open(root+"/"+name,'r')
            line = outfile2.readline()
            while line:
                #print(line)

                if line[0]!="\"":

                    print(line)
                    outfile1.write(line)
                    outfile1.write("\n")
                line = outfile2.readline()  
            outfile2.close()
            outfile1.close()
```

I am trying to read every file from the directory and in each file I am trying to omit the lines which have a " in the starting and saving these corrected files in a new directory.But I am getting empty files in the new directory.

Comment: Are you sure you have non-empty text files in "currentdir" and they have lines in them not starting with "? There are minor problems with your code, but in principle it looks working here.

Comment: @mkiever yes I have a print line which is printing the correct non" lines

Comment: Well, I saved your code in an otherwise empty folder as "oswalk.py", use currentdir = '.' and created a resultdir outside: resultdir = '../oswalkout'. If I run "python3 oswalk.py" it's replicating the file in '../oswalkout' (except for the minor problems). You're doing something odd with currentdir/resultdir (like being equal or contained in one another)?